# add to chrome button not showing in chrome webstore

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have created a chrome app and publish in chrome store but only showing visit website button and add to chrome button not showing.
I am new in chrome app development.

so can you please help me?

chrome store app url
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shopselo-retailer/olbldeknijedkfloekkoefllmghddhcl/null

Screenshot
https://screenshot.net/1eoypa8

Comment: Show your manifest.json please. Apps are not extensions. These two are two different things even though they have similarities. Here's what I see: 1) The web store shows your item in the "extensions" category. 2) I can't fetch the source of the item via CRXViewer.

Comment: {
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "shopselo - Retailer",
"description": "App to manage your shop from one place and many more...",
"version": "1.1",
"icons": {
"128": "128.png"
},
"app": {
"urls": [
"http://159.65.145.129/chromeApp/shopselo"
],
"launch": {
"web_url": "http://159.65.145.129/rnd/retailer"
}
},
"permissions": [
"unlimitedStorage",
"notifications"
]
}

Comment: Acctually what i want 
i have a website and i just make that to chrome app.
i use applicationize.me to create the crx file which is working fine in chrome developer mode 

So how can i publish that crx to chrome store?

Comment: This is a hosted app, which isn't supported in Chrome since 2017. The reason was probably that a hosted app is not really doing anything, it's just a bookmark pointing to a site.

Comment: So, can you help me how can i create chrome app which will open my web app within a window not browser

Comment: You'll need to rewrite it as a packaged chrome app (only on ChromeOS for the new apps) or as a PWA. Look for tutorials.